# Options for programmatically serving data from a pc

Tags: c#, .net, wifi

I'm working on a .Net application which will serve files and other structured data to mobile devices from a PC, over a wifi network.

What are standard ways of doing this? My first instinct is to think of the PC as a web service host, but I don't want to have users host a web server for this purpose.

Is this what Bonjour can be used for? How PC friendly is that, or are there any obvious alternatives?

Comment: Do you just want to be able to browse files on your PC from mobile devices?  Would a simple SMB share work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[brianestey recommends using SMB shares](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514260/options-for-programmatically-serving-data-from-a-pc#comment-10541183), but those are handled via system-level filesystem exporting code, which are executing with essentially administrator level privileges. I'm sure Microsoft has gone to great lengths in the last five or six years to really improve the security of this layer but it still seems a bit too much privileges to give away.

Instead, running a web server on the host allows you to configure the filesystem and system privileges for whatever account runs the web server, allowing you to confine the web server according to the [Principle of Least Authority](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_authority), and constrain the results of possible security flaws in the software.

Of course, if you're just going to run the web server as Administrator, then it is probably a moot point -- you need to ask yourself who you think can do a better job writing secure software, Apache or Microsoft.

Comment: I don't think an SMB share will work, since I need access to meta data and processing of those files when they are served. So there needs to be some sort of wrapper. For example, if an image is requested, it may be resized to the mobile devices resolution as needed.

Comment: I'll look into web server options

Comment: Then a web server is probably a good approach; HTTP beats e.g. FTP any day of the week, and there are enough tools out there to process images through a web server that it would be pretty straightforward to re-write images on the fly on the way out the door.